# DOMWindow on page load

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this question repeats, but I couldn't find solution for my problem. I have something like this:

```
<p><a href="#inlineContent" class="defaultDOMWindow">Open DOM Window</a></p> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.defaultDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({ 
eventType:'click', 
loader:1, 
loaderImagePath:'animationProcessing.gif', 
loaderHeight:16, 
loaderWidth:17  
}); 
</script> 
<div id="inlineContent" style=" display:none;"> 
<p>Inline Content</p> 
<p>Click overlay to close window</p> 
<p>Consequat ea Investigationes in enim congue. Option velit volutpat quod blandit ex.</p> 
<p>Erat usus lorem adipiscing non in. Nobis claram iusto et dolore facilisis. Claritatem decima velit decima ipsum wisi. Quinta ullamcorper sollemnes usus aliquip in. Ut aliquip velit tempor facit putamus. Habent duis et option quod facer. Delenit facer consequat seacula molestie notare. Qui tincidunt nobis lectores eleifend eorum. Decima usus facer id parum legere. Nonummy nonummy facilisis sit qui eodem. </p> 
</div>
```

And I want to change it to show dom window on page load. So I want to remove this link and set function to load dom window on page load.  How can I do this? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This is first example on http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html

Comment: Is your html inside html tags?

Comment: yes it is. I just didn't put it.

Comment: No. As I said, I need to remove link and set to show Dom window on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this workaround:

```
 $('.defaultDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
     eventType: 'click',
     loader: 1,
     loaderImagePath: 'animationProcessing.gif',
     loaderHeight: 16,
     loaderWidth: 17
 })
 $(window).load(function () {
     $('.defaultDOMWindow').trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: this is great! It's working now! But is there a way to load window without link?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know this plugin and i'm not sure what you call link (<a> tag?). You should open a new question and provide a sample test (a jsfiddle would be great).

Comment: Ok,htnaks for this. I just put `display:none` as attribute to link and I don't need to change anything else. Thanks again!